# Android - connection timeouts when 2+ devices connected to same wifi router

Tags: android, http, networking, okhttp

I am developing android application which acts as client for our server which is providing REST http api. In android app I am using OkHttp library for http requests (nothing special here). However, I am observing strange behavior when I am using app on two or more devices connected to same wifi router at the same time (using = sending http requests) - I am getting connection timeout exception on all devices except one. When I stop using app on all devices for about 30 seconds I can successfully send http request from any device.

I have tested more wifi routers and same thing happens. I was thinking that this might be server issue - i.e. somehow refuesing connections from same IP but from different port - but I was assured that server is not configured in this way.

Do you have some experience of same bahavior? And do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: Hi Richard, I started to face similar issue. Did you manage to fix it? (I found several issues reported on github related to okhttp but, unfortunately, suggestions there didn't fix the issue)

Comment: Hi, Im facing the same issue but using **advanced http cordova plugin with ionic 4** tested same thing, 2 devices, same wifi = timeout, inmediatly i turn off wifi in one and connect to mobile data and both works perfectly